# Get responseBody from HttpServletResponse Java

Tags: java, spring

I want to check response body, read the response then perform some other operation manipulate the body and then return the response.

How exactly can i log the response in logger?
If i want to manipulate the content of response how can i do that?

Custom Filter.java

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Order(1)
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"/*"}, description = "My delay filter ")
public class CustomFilter implements Filter{
    
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        
        try {
            if (httpRequest.getRequestURL().toString().contains("download")) {
                logger.debug(httpResponse); //want to log response body

                
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception in CustomFilter.doFilter(): ", e);
        }
        
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }


    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Assuming you're ok including spring-web, there's a `ContentCachingResponseWrapper`.  Your filter can construct one of those (and return it up the chain) out of the response it receives, and read and log the response from it (since it will allow you to reuse the stream).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.biclinical.rmm.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.util.ContentCachingRequestWrapper;
import org.springframework.web.util.ContentCachingResponseWrapper;
import org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils;

import com.biclinical.rmm.utility.ServiceUtils;

@Component
@Order(1)
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = { "/*" })
public class DownloadFileFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DownloadFileFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest requestToCache = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request);
        HttpServletResponse responseToCache = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response);

        try {
            if (requestToCache.getRequestURL().toString().contains("/download")) {
                chain.doFilter(request, responseToCache);
                getResponseData(responseToCache);

            } else {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception in CustomFilter.doFilter(): ", e);
        }

    }

    private static void getResponseData(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper wrapper = WebUtils.getNativeResponse(response,
                ContentCachingResponseWrapper.class);
        if (wrapper != null) {
            byte[] buf = wrapper.getContentAsByteArray();
            if (buf.length > 0) {
                String payload = new String(buf, 0, buf.length, wrapper.getCharacterEncoding());
                logger.debug("Response Richa :" + payload);
                wrapper.copyBodyToResponse();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```